# get the duration of running shell script in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a shell script (kill.sh) that will determine the elapsed time of the current script (loop.sh, which I previously ran). when loop.sh reaches 10 minutes, kill.sh will kill the process. Please help

EDIT:

this would be the contents of the shell script loop.sh which will basically loops infinitely.
I want to create a script that will determine the duration of the loop.sh and will kill
it if reaches 10 minutes

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo "Do something; hit [CTRL+C] to stop!"
done
```

the kill.sh could be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
PROC_ID=$(ps -ef | grep "loop.sh" | grep -v grep | cut -c10-15)
...some codes here to get the duration of the loop.sh if it reaches 10 minutes.

if [ "$PROC_ID" != 0 -a (elapsed time is equal or more than 10 minutes) ];
then
    kill -9 "$PROC_ID"
else
    echo "NOT FOUND!"
fi
```

Comment: `I want to create a shell script` -- Please feel free to do so.  Feel free to post your code once you're done.

Answer (score 2):

This script help you to find the elapsed time in `seconds`

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)

#do your work

end=$(date +%s)
elapsed=$(( $end - $start ))
echo "$elapsed sec"
```

EDIT:

```
#/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)
elapsed=0
while [ $elapsed -le 600 ] # 60*10=600 seconds 
do
    #do your work
    end=$(date +%s)
    elapsed=$(( $end - $start ))
done
kill -9 "$pid" #pid of the script
```

Comment: yes. how am I going to do that with another shell script (kill.sh) to do the job in determining the elapsed time for the loop.sh. when it reaches 10minutes, it will kill the loop.sh process

Answer (score 2):

How about starting the script in the background, then starting a sleep in the background as well, and waiting for either to finish.  If the sleep finishes first, kill the script.

```
loop.sh & { sleep 600; kill %1 2>/dev/null; }
```

Comment: I would just want to retain my original logic of the program. the first script that I want to create lets say loop.sh loops infinitely, then my second script which I named to be kill.sh will going to check if loop.sh runs for 10minutes already, if it is already 10 minutes kill.sh will going to kill the loop.sh process

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree +1 The above does check if it ran for 10 minutes. That said if you don't like it, can you tell me what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: just to clarify, is the code above will be the contents of my kill.sh?

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree For my answer yes. For Alfe's answer, they can be if you want to use it to start loop.sh, otherwise you can just alias loop.sh="/path/to/loop.sh & { sleep 600; kill %1 2>/dev/null; }" or put the fork logic directly in loop.sh or in kill.sh if you want to start loop from there or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like below. Note `-C` option for `ps` isn't found on every system, so do something similar to what you were doing to get pid and time, though I would still use `-o` (e.g. on some os x I would do something like `ps -axo start,pid,command | awk '$NF == "loop.sh" {print $1 " " $2}'` or something similar). Also I wouldn't use `kill -9` unless it won't exit for some reason otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date -d $(ps -C loop.sh -o start=) '+%s' 2>/dev/null)
timeup=$(($start + 600 )) #10*60=600
pid=$(ps -C loop.sh -o pid=)

if [[ -z $pid ]]; then
  echo "NOT FOUND!"
elif [[ $(date '+%s') > $timeup ]]; then
  kill -9 "$pid"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easily achieved via the sleep command:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROC_ID=$(ps -ef | grep "loop.sh" | grep -v grep | cut -c10-15)

sleep 10m

if [ "$PROC_ID" != 0 ];
then
    kill -9 "$PROC_ID"
else
    echo "NOT FOUND!"
fi
```

Comment: I guess you could fork above directly from "loop.sh" as soon as it starts, but that seems overly hackish. Otherwise, how do you guarantee that they start at the same time (so that other script ran for 10 minutes)?

Comment: Basically, I want to call kill.sh within loop.sh just to check if loop.sh
has been running too long for 10 minutes. if it is running for more than 10m,
kill.sh it will kill the process, else it will do nothing.